# Two Displays at two Graphic Cards

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, radeon, fglrx

I am trying to set up two Displays on Ubuntu 14.10

Display 1 @ AMD R9 290
Display 2 @ AMD Radeon HD 7870

If I install the AMD (FGLRX) Driver it is not possible to activate Display 2 in the Catalyst Control Center. I click on <kbd>activate and Reboot the System</kbd> but it doesn't work and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reboot your machine and go to Root shell over Recovery Mode
2. Create an `xorg.conf`

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   Xorg -configure
   mv xorg.conf.new xorg.conf
   mv xorg.conf /etc/X11/
   ```
3. Reboot your Machine
4. Open your `xorg.conf`

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
5. Change your `xorg.conf` in section `ServerLayout` to this:

   ```
   Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier "**Multihead**"
   Screen  "screen0"
   Screen  "screen1" RightOf "screen0"
   InputDevice     "mouse1" "CorePointer"
   InputDevice     "keyboard1" "CoreKeyboard"
   **Option "Xinerama"** 
   EndSection
   ```
6. Reboot your system

NOW IT WORKS !!!

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to properly use both screens, your cards must be Crossfire compatible.  Since both of your cards are, we can now connect the two cards with a ribbon called a CrossfireX Cable.  CrossfireX and SLi allow you to connect two or more cards as a single entity on a desktop motherboard.  You must turn your PC off, open the shell of the Tower in which the two cards are sitting.  Then take one end of the Crossfire and find the male version on top of the Card.  This is usually located near the front of the card.
[image]

The next step is to find the other cards male connector as connect it.  You should now have something like this.
[image]

Now that you have your physical issues addressed, we can now move on to the Digital problem.  In order for your desktop to proper use the second screen, you must tell Ubuntu to extend the desktop to a second screen.  In order to do this you must connect both monitors with what ever ports you decide.  When you boot up Ubuntu, you need to go to System Settings, which should be located on your Taskbar.  Then head to Display.  There you should see two screens.[image]

Comment: The two graphics cards will not run in the crossfire operation.The target is a system in which the R9 is passed to a virtual Windows machine (QEMU / KVM - Device Passtrough).

Answer (score 0):

The two graphics cards will not run in the crossfire operation.The target is a system in which the R9 is passed to a virtual Windows machine (QEMU / KVM - Device Passtrough)

The problem is, that i cant activate Display 2 without crossfire.